# How do you name "javascript:" prefix in inline event handlers?

Tags: javascript, naming

In the following code:

```
<a onclick="javascript:alert()">
```

how do you name the `javascript:` part? Protocol, pseudo-protocol, scheme, label, prefix?

I am only trying to figure out a common name for it, not technically correct term based on what it actually is at the end. So when I say for example "javascript protocol" most people would be able understand what I mean. (I need to use this in a documentation)

Answer (score 2):

> < a onclick="javascript:alert()">

I don't believe using `javascript:` in anything other than the `href` attribute is even valid (though it appears browsers will still execute it - I believe this is because technically `javascript:` in this context is a **label**, are you planning to `goto javascript;`?).

Also, it's considered very bad form to use inline event handlers like that.  And if I'm not mistaken it's even been deprecated by W3C.

But, fwiw, when `javascript:` is used in an `href` it is called a "pseudo-protocol identifier".

Comment: You could use it to break an outer loop. But even that purpose is essentially forgotten.

Comment: @Reid: and completely irrelevant (for use) in an inline event handler.